# Rotational Values with Constraints

Tags: constraints, bone.constraints

Is there any way to have the rotational values updating "live" on an object with a contraint? I would like to access the y axis rotation to use it with a driver but with the contraint acting on the object the value doesn't update at all.

Comment: as you can see in the overwhelming comments and answers....the reason might be how you asked your question: without any information what you did exactly. So pls provide blend file to attract more people. Also a sketch/image/link to animation what you want to have to make it clear would help to improve your question.

Comment: I have to agree with Chris.. this question would be much improved by illustrating the general problem with your particular case.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing something like "Limit Rotation":

[image]

Then you can enable "Affect Transform" option: [image]

[image]

Sometimes there is no such option, for example with "Copy Rotation" - here the middle object copies the rotation of the left object, and the right object has a driver based on the middle object (the driver fails):

[image]

In such cases you can modify your driver to read the value after the constraint has been applied, so rather than reading the property, you read from the *Transform Channel*:

[image]